# код с C++ на Python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

В рациях я перешёл с С++ на Python решил опробовать свои в одной задачке, но не получилось :( А получилось только на С++, можете ли вы помочь с переписыванием кода на С++ в Python код
вот С++ код:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n,m,j;

int main()
{
    cin>>n>>m;
    while(m>=(j-1)%n+1)
    {
        m-=(j-1)%n+1;
        j++;
    }
    cout<<m;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сами. Вместо cin в Python есть input(). Вместо cout print(). Вместо фигурных скобок Python используются отступы.

И да, учтите, что я не знаю ни С++, ни Python. А узнал я всё это через беглое гугление. Это я всё к тому, что предлагаю вам хотя бы попытаться, иначе ваш вопрос кто-нибудь да закроет.

Comment: [Ввод и вывод](https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/inout_and_arithmetic_operations/) данных, цикл [while](https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/while/) ну и немного про [переменные и типы данных](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.2.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В `c++` целочисленная переменная объявленная вне функции (глобальная переменная) по умолчанию имеет значение `0`.

Тогда на строчке с циклом `while` у нас произойдет вот такая операция:

```
while(m >= (0 - 1) % n + 1)
```

Например пусть `m = 20, n = 10`, тогда в строчке выше, операция `-1 % 10` в `c++` вернет `-1`, а в `python` результат этой же операции будет `9`.

Так же т.к. автор не дал ни условия задачи, ни ограничений для `m` и `n`, то предположу, что `n > 0`, а для `m` думаю любое значение.

Тогда, чтобы не было проблемы описанной выше, можно перед циклом пройти эту итерацию отдельно:

```py
# n > 1 т.к. при n == 1 операция -1 % 1 вернет и там, и там 0
if n > 1 and m >= 1:
    j = 1
```

В итоге получаем такой код:

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
j = 0

if n > 1 and m >= 0:
    j = 1

while m >= (j - 1) % n + 1:
    m -= (j - 1) % n + 1
    j += 1
    
print(m)
```

Не знаю зачем вам код на `python` если вы написали на `c++`, но на будущее все, что я написал выше очень просто гуглится, это говорит вам человек, который не пишет на `python`

**P.S.** Нашел на [github](https://github.com/andreikop/cpp2python) конвертер из `c++` в `python` код, не знаю, точно как там все работает, не проверял, но думаю для маленький задач сгодится :)